# Android Urban Airship Landing page closes after a while

Tags: android, action, urbanairship.com

I have integrated urban Airship to my android project. The problem I have is that when I push a notification with a landing page as an action,I receive the notification I click on this,the app launches, the landing page opens for 2-3 seconds and then goes to my MainActivity.class. But it should stay on  Landing page. 
I have defined as a parent activity of the com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity at manifest xml the MainAcitvity.class.
Any help plz?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What SDK version are you using? A fix was introduced in 5.0.2 where the landing page could launch before the app is able to launch. If you are using an older version, you should update and see if that fixes your issue.

Please contact Urban Airship support and provide your manifest, build.gradle, and your custom push receiver if you have one.